# Is the internal CPU microcode ever rewritten?

Tags: cpu

Does the firmware inside the physical CPU ever get rewritten, so it can be updated with time, or does it always need a "software" (higher level provided) microcode to take its place for latest bugfixes?
Are the same SKUs shipped with different microcodes, depending on the time they left the factory?